# Registry functions for modern apps

Tags: uwp, registry, win32-process

I want to use the APIs like [RegCloseKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regclosekey) inside an UWP application.

Can we use these APIs in modern apps? or these APIs are just for win32 apps?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Native UWP applications cannot directly manipulate the registry. At present, if your application is closely related to the registry, you can consider creating a win32 application, or, as Nick said, use desktop-bridge related technologies to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can read registry values from a Win32 runFullTrust background
>   process launched from a UWP application, and you can write values in
>   the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE hive from an "elevated" Win32 application
>   launched from that runFullTrust process.
>
> These techniques are powerful and using them in a UWP app deployed
>   from the Windows Store requires special scrutiny and permission from
>   Microsoft. The techniques are used by OEMs, but not exclusively
>   restricted to them. If you have a good reason and are able to explain
>   it, you're likely to get approval.