# How Can I edit the registry with C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

"You was read registry values from a Win32 runFullTrust background process launched from a UWP application, and you can write values in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive from an "elevated" Win32 application launched from that runFullTrust process." follow link

> [Registry functions for modern apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970684/registry-functions-for-modern-apps)

I tried on this solution but I have some problems. I did not get registry values.

ex: "The Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameDVR has AppCaptureEnabled key and value of AppCaptureEnabled is 1. I run execute win32app and get value of AppCaptureEnabled = 1. When I call execute win32app file from UWP app and get value of AppCaptureEnabled = 0."

The source code such as below:

```
            string value64 = string.Empty;
            string value32 = string.Empty;

            RegistryKey localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64);
            localKey = localKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameDVR", true);
            if (localKey != null)
            {
                value64 = localKey.GetValue("AppCaptureEnabled").ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("AppCaptureEnabled = " + value64);
            }
            RegistryKey localKey32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32);
            localKey32 = localKey32.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameDVR", true);
            if (localKey32 != null)
            {
                value32 = localKey32.GetValue("AppCaptureEnabled").ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("AppCaptureEnabled = " + value32);
            }
```

Please help me explain why I can not get/save value of key?

Comment: `If I run win32app to edit the registry then result was right. But, when I call execute win32app file from UWP app then then result was right.` something wrong here?

Comment: It is wrong -> It is "If I run win32app to edit the registry then result was right. But, when I call execute win32app file from UWP app then then result was wrong" => Such as: "The Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameDVR has AppCaptureEnabled key and value of AppCaptureEnabled is 1. I run execute win32app and get value of AppCaptureEnabled = 1 when I call execute win32app file from UWP app and get value of AppCaptureEnabled = 0."

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say the result was wrong.  What did it do / did not do?

Comment: Can you refer stefan's blog [App Elevation](https://stefanwick.com/2018/10/01/app-elevation-samples-part-1/) to allowElevation?

Comment: Yes, What did it not do? why I can not set value of key?

Comment: it's hard to say, if you have Elevated win32, it could edit registry successfully, could you mind share [mcve]?